# Embed JS Console within website

Tags: html, console, javascript

I want to embed a JS-Console within a website for extended debugging purposes. Are there any libraries or hooks available? How can I catch console.log messages?

Answer (score 7):

> How can I catch console.log messages?

You can monkey-patch the real `console.log` method and do whatever you like with the input:

```
var realConsoleLog = console.log;
console.log = function () {
    var message = [].join.call(arguments, " ");
    // Display the message somewhere... (jQuery example)
    $(".output").text(message);
    realConsoleLog.apply(console, arguments);
};
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/SWRDP/). It logs calls to `console.log` in the `.output` element, as well as in the console like usual.

Answer (score 2):

You can override console.log

```
<div id="console"></div>
```

script :

```
if (window.console) console = { 
    log: function(){
        var output='',
            console=document.getElementById('console');
        for (var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) {
            output+=arguments[i]+' ';
        }
        console.innerText+=output+"\n";
    }
};

//test
var test=12345;
console.log('test', 'xyz', test);
```